# How to obtain certain lines from several texts simultaneously?

Tags: linux, command-line

Suppose I have 100 texts under the same dir, i.e., text1.txt, text2.txt,...,text100.txt. I want to extract certain lines(e.g., first 100 lines)from each text, and save the lines to another new 100 texts respectively,that is, **each new text has 100 lines**.

I know `head -100 text1.txt > text1_new.txt`, `head -100 text2.txt > text2_new.txt` ... can make it. But are there any more efficient methods to extract them simultaneously in the terminal?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are the 100 texts all in one directory?  If not, do they have a common file name convention to distinguish them?

Comment: You could use a find command to loop through a directory of files:  `find /my/directory/of/files/ -type f -exec head -100 '{}' >> ~/consolidated.txt \;` If this works for you let me know and I'll leave a detailed answer.

Comment: @Patrick my interpretation is that they want 100 new files, not one consolidated one. (text1__100.txt)

Comment: @Patrick Yes, I want to 100 new files with 100 line in each of them, not a consolidated file with 1000 lines. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffSchaller sorry for the confusing name in my question, you're right, I want another 100 new files from original files, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
find . -name "text*.txt" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'f="{}"; head -100 "$f" > "${f%.txt}_new.txt"'
```

- `find . -name "text*.txt" -type f` finds all text files in the directory
- `-print0` prints the file path with a null character to preserve spaces
- `xargs -0` takes the null terminated arguments
- `-I{}` is used as placeholder for the argument
- `sh -c` executes dash with a command string
- `f="{}"` saves the argument in variable `f`
- `head -100 "$f"` the head command
- `"${f%.txt}_new.txt"` replaces ".txt" with "_new.txt" in the argument

Comment: Instead of  `xargs` you could `find -exec sh -c 'head -100 "$1" > "${1%.txt}_new.txt"' find-sh {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate across the files

```
for f in *.txt
do
    head -n100 "$f" > "${f%.txt}_new.txt"
done
```

The caveat is that the `*.txt` will expand at the moment it's reached, to list all files that match. If you've already run this script (partially or completely) it will match some of the results files too. Solutions are either to delete them before running (`rm *_new.txt`), or to tighten the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "parallel", use [`parallel`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/parallel.1.html)

```
shopt -s extglob
parallel sh -c 'out="${1%.txt}_new.txt"; head -n 100 "$1" > "$out"' _ -- !(*_new).txt
```

I'm assuming your shell is bash, and using [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) to loop over the text files that are **not** the *_new.txt ones